# How to remove applications on a Mac

Tags: macos

I've installed some software on my Mac, such as R language environment, .djvu file reader, etc.

How do I remove them? There's no "Control Panel -> Add/Remove programs..."

I'm using a Mac Book Pro, but I suppose it's the same on all Macs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get rid of the application, you can just drag it to the trash.

There might be a few leftover files in  `~/Library/Application Support/` and `~/Library/Preferences/`; there are a few ways of getting there.

1. You can check by going to the Finder, the "Go" menu, holding down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key, and choosing "Library". Just drag those to the trash, too.
2. Or, you can copy one of the above paths, go to Finder, the "Go" menu, then "Go to Folder" and paste the location.

Find and drag those leftovers to the trash, too.

Comment: so easy! no registry key hazard.. love it! :D

Comment: Yeah, that gets rid of most of the stuff. Sometimes they'll leave something in Macintosh HD/Library/Application Support, too, but — especially if you just installed by dragging to /Applications, or via the App Store — ~/Library/Application Support/{appname} will get nearly everything.

Comment: @athos: You would think there is no registry. It's what Apple calls the launch services database, it's not the same but even on Mac after cleaning all the files there are still left overs of applications in this DB after uninstall. It's a huge database where every application ever used, even from external drives and virtual drives like a DMG are all stored permanently in this database until re-installation. Having an editable registry instead of an non editable growing invisible database doesn't sound so bad afterward right?

Comment: @Locutus: Can you explain why having a registry is an advantage?

Comment: To @Buscar 웃: Please don't remove the original method of my answer when you edit.

Comment: Well it looks like you accepted my suggestion in your edit anyway.

Answer (score 5):

I use [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) to uninstall apps and their associated configuration files as well.

However you should always look to see if the application you installed comes with an uninstaller, some of the bigger apps do, and use that first.

Answer (score 1):

Please Note: [this question is basically a dup of this earlier question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50767/is-there-a-standard-uninstall-procedure-on-mac-os-x/)

I use a one liner borrowed from a user somewhere else on this site, or related sister site, or from macosxhints (I no longer remember the reference or I'd post a link), that I turned into a script (called "uninstaller") and adjusted slightly by changing the rm command to using a safer command line program installed using macports, rmtrash. The user provided bom receipt file should be in /private/var/db/receipts if the application to be removed was installed using an installer and the dev included one. The script will place all files installed into the user's Trash.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 #uninstaller /private/var/db/receipts/com.url.name.of.app.bom
 #uninstall os x application installed with installer -pkg
 #using (user) provided bom receipt
 #place all installed files and directories in user's Trash

 lsbom="/usr/bin/lsbom"
 cd="/usr/bin/cd"
 sudo="/usr/bin/sudo"
 xargs="/usr/bin/xargs"
 rmtrash="/opt/local/bin/rmtrash"

 lsbom -fls "$1" | (cd /; sudo xargs rmtrash -u $USER)
 exit
```

Installing [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) and rmtrash is simple enough, however, once xcode (for Mavericks 10.9 [xcode_5.1.1.dmg](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=Developer_Tools/xcode_5.1.1/xcode_5.1.1.dmg)) is installed:

```
 curl -Ok https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-2.2.1.tar.bz2
 tar xf MacPorts-2.2.1.tar.bz2
 cd MacPorts-2.2.1
 ./configure
 make
 sudo make install #not war!
 cd ..
 rm -rf Macports-*
 sudo /opt/local/bin/port -v selfupdate
 export PATH=$HOME/macports/bin:$HOME/macports/sbin:$PATH
 export MANPATH=$HOME/macports/share/man:$MANPATH
 sudo port -vsc install rmtrash
 diskutil quiet repairPermissions /
```

Comment: I like this. I really like this.